# Basic Linkedin authentication with Symfony 2

Tags: php, symfony, linkedin-api

I'm actually working on the Linkedin API with Symfony 2 to learn more but I'm having a conception problem. Here we go.

I'm using a route called /linkedin/auth to launch the authentication phase, it is actually calling indexAction.

The first step of this method is to perform a redirection that provokes a request response of Linkedin.

The second step is to collect the CODE in this request to ask for an access token (OAuth2 protocol).

The problem is between the two steps : using header() to redirect without exit() won't redirect me so I won't never collect the informations I need but if I call exit() the second method won't be call.

I tried a tricky move creating a route with the same path than the Linkedin response to call my second method but it didn't worked.

I don't want to create a button or something like that after the Linkedin response to go to the second step.. Do you have any idea ? (with Symfony2 logic)

```
public function indexAction()
{
    $this->getAuthorizationCode();
    $this->getAccessToken();
    return $this->render(foo, array());
}

private function getAuthorizationCode()
{
    $params = array('response_type' => 'code',
                    'client_id' => API_KEY,
                    'state' => STATE,
                    'redirect_uri' => REDIRECT_URI,
                   );
    $url = 'https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth2/authorization?' . http_build_query($params);
    header(Location: $url); // Problem is here
    #exit; die(); whatever();
}

private function getAccessToken()
{
    $request = $this->getRequest();
    var_dump($request->query->get('code'));
    $params = array('grant_type' => 'authorization_code',
                    'client_id' => API_KEY,
                    'client_secret' => API_SECRET,
                    'code' => $request->query->get('code'),
                    'redirect_uri' => REDIRECT_URI,
        );
    $url = 'https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth2/accessToken?' . http_build_query($params);
    $context = stream_context_create(
            array('http' => 
                array('method' => 'POST',
                    )
                )
            );
    $response = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
    $token = json_decode($response);
    $_SESSION['access_token'] = $token->access_token;
    $_SESSION['expires_in'] = $token->expires_in;
    $_SESSION['expires_at'] = time() + $_SESSION['expires_in'];
    return true;
}
```

Comment: why do you use ```header(Location: $url);``` there is ```$this->redirect($url);``` for redirects.

Comment: I tried it too this morning but didn't worked.

Comment: I'm not familiar with linkedin api, but I've googled for it, and found this: https://packagist.org/search/?tags=linkedin . Chose One, and keep calm.

Comment: I took time to think about that and after reflexion HWI is not appropriate. I don't need to connect a user to his social network but to always use the admin one to search after things that I can display on my website after that. Still searching..